# Play framework session management

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I know we can create session in Play while redirecting like

```
OK(200,"Welcome").withSession("username","jack")
```

However I wan to create session before redirect and take decision accordingly like

```
val session: Session = new Session
session.+("username","jack")
```

Answer (score 1):

Session is essentially a `Map[String, String]`, and `withSession` expects `(String, String)*` (varargs like `"a" -> "aVal", "b", -> "bVal" ...`).
So, try something like this:

```
val mySession = Map("a" -> "valuOfA")
OK(200,"Welcome").withSession(mySession.toSeq: _*)
```

The syntax `: _*` is used to pass a `Seq` as varargs.